# C#: Workbook SaveAs saving with macro in it

Tags: c#, excel, windows-server-2008-r2

Below is my code where I copy worksheet and save it as new file,it actually saves without macro in my local where we have environment as 
    Office 2003,Windows Server 2003

But in server it saves with macro,which I dont want 
Environment is Office 2003,Windows Server 2008

C#:

```
try
            {
                wBook = xCel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);                
                wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                    
                wSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                    
                wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Sheets[1];
                wSheet.SaveAs(ExcelCopyPath);
             }

            catch {}
            finally
            {                
                if (wBook != null)
                {                    
                    wBook.Close();
                    wSheet = null;
                    wBook = null;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                if (Excel.ProcessID > 0)
                 {

                    Process pxCel = Process.GetProcessById(Excel.ProcessID);
                    pxCel.Kill();
                 }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();                
                try { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wSheet);}
                catch {}                                        
                try { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wBook);}
                catch {}                
            }
```

Please check my problem...and suggest some answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Log your exceptions like so:

```
try
{
    wBook = xCel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);                
    wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                    
    wSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                    
    wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Sheets[1];
    wSheet.SaveAs(ExcelCopyPath);
 }

catch(Exception ex) 
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\mylog.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("First catch block");
        sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
finally
{                
    if (wBook != null)
    {                    
        wBook.Close();
        wSheet = null;
        wBook = null;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (Excel.ProcessID > 0)
     {

        Process pxCel = Process.GetProcessById(Excel.ProcessID);
        pxCel.Kill();
     }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();                
    try { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wSheet);}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\mylog.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Second catch block");
        sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}                                     
    try { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wBook);}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\mylog.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Third catch block");
        sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}              
}
```

You should really use a logging framework like NLog, but this should help you out in the short term. This won't solve your problem, but at least now you will be able to open `C:\temp\mylog.txt` and see what has gone wrong and this will help you diagnose the issue. With empty catch blocks, you will never be able to solve problems because you will never be able to figure out what has gone wrong.